# Regex expression that matches URLs if it contains one pattern but not another

Tags: regex, web-crawler

I need to create a regex pattern that will match against all urls that contain String1 but not String2.  The the problem is that a URL can contain both String1 and String2.  For example, if crawling an e-commerce site I want to collect the catalog pages without getting the product URLs.

Example Catalog URL: http://www.domain.com/catalog/name  String1: catalog

Example Product URL: http://www.domain.com/catalog/name/product/id  =>  String2: product

Using the the sample URLs above, String1 is "catalog" and String2 is "product".  My current pattern to get the catalog URLs is `\/catalog(?:\/[\w-\/]*)?$`

How do I extend this pattern to skip all URLs with String2?

Comment: easiest is to just use two expressions. get your URLs in the first. in the second, see if "product" is a substring of the URL and if so, don't use it.

Comment: Thanks @aleph_null but I was able to get it working using `\/catalog(?:\/[\w-]*)?(?!.*\/product\/)`

It matches against "/catalog" and then optionally any part of the url that satisfies an alpha-numeric character or hyphen except when it's followed by "/product/".

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for a [negative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

For instance, this regex:

```
catalog\/name\/(?!product)
```

Matches ([example](http://rubular.com/r/toexWU4cga)):

```
http://www.domain.com/catalog/name/produc/id
```

However, it doesn't match ([example](http://rubular.com/r/ESKUKV1tSq)):

```
http://www.domain.com/catalog/name/product/id
```

Hope this helps!